# Weird Json conversion error using lambda

Tags: c#, json, lambda

I have a Json document being sent to a Web API that is converted to an array of Addresses.  If I send one address the following code works, but if I send two it dies a nasty death.  Any ideas?

Input to web service that is failing looks like this:

```
[
  "\"TrackingIdTest_2\"",
  "[
  {\"CustomerAddressKey\":\"1\",\"Address\":\"6069 W STUDIO CT\",\"City\":\"LOS ANGELES\",\"State\":\"CA\",\"Zipcode\":\"\"}
  ,{\"CustomerAddressKey\":\"2\",\"Address\":\"1095 6th Ave\",\"City\":\"NEW YORK\",\"State\":\"NY\",\"Zipcode\":\"\"}
  ]"
]
```

If I send this it works:

```
[
  "\"TrackingIdTest_2\"",
  "[
  {\"CustomerAddressKey\":\"1\",\"Address\":\"6069 W STUDIO CT\",\"City\":\"LOS ANGELES\",\"State\":\"CA\",\"Zipcode\":\"\"}
  ]"
]
```

The code that is throws the error is the following:

```
var addressesInternal = new List<RequestAddressInternal>();
addresses.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
   addressesInternal.Add(new RequestAddressInternal()
   {
     InternalAddressKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     RequestAddress = x
   });
 });
```

Addresses is defined like so:

```
RequestAddress[] addresses
// Defined in a Model class:
public class RequestAddress
{
    public string CustomerAddressKey { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
}
```

RequestAddressInternal looks like this:

```
public class RequestAddressInternal
{
    public string InternalAddressKey { get; set; }
    public RequestAddress RequestAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get back from the web service is this:

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.IsValidChildType(XmlNodeType type)\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode newChild)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeWrapper.AppendChild(IXmlNode newChild)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.CreateElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String elementName, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String elementPrefix, Dictionary`2 attributeNameValues)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadElement(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, IXmlNode currentNode, String propertyName, XmlNamespaceManager manager)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeValue(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, String propertyName, IXmlNode currentNode)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode(JsonReader reader, IXmlDocument document, XmlNamespaceManager manager, IXmlNode currentNode)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(String value, String deserializeRootElementName, Boolean writeArrayAttribute)\r\n   at Midas.WebApi.waCarrierServiceabilityLib.CarrierServiceabilityImpl.ProcessBulkImpl(String serviceRequest, String clientId, String clientRequestTrackingId, RequestAddress[] addresses, String clientOwner, String uid, String ipAddress, Boolean includeGeodata) in E:\\Source Code\\GitHub\\waCarrierServiceability\\waCarrierServiceabilityLib\\CarrierServiceabilityImpl.cs:line 222\r\n   at Midas.WebApi.waCarrierServiceabilityLib.CarrierServiceabilityImpl.ProcessBulk(String serviceRequest, JArray requestRaw, String clientId, String clientOwner, String userId, String ipAddress, Boolean includeGeodata) in E:\\Source Code\\GitHub\\waCarrierServiceability\\waCarrierServiceabilityLib\\CarrierServiceabilityImpl.cs:line 134\r\n   at Midas.WebApi.waCarrierServiceability.Controllers.CarrierServiceabilityController.GetCarrierServiceabilityBulk(JArray jsonParamList) in E:\\Source Code\\GitHub\\waCarrierServiceability\\Controllers\\CarrierServiceability.cs:line 120\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

At this point I'm wondering if it's some time type of threading issues?  I wrapped the code that is the last to execute in a try catch and caught exception, however no exception was thrown, it just never makes it to the next line in the code.

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: I ended up bailing on this and using a strongly typed input object from a JArray input object.  That fixed my issue.  As for which JSON Library I'm using, that is Newtonsoft.Json V9.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to give a complete answer unfortunately, but having a look, a couple of things that might be worth trying:

1. It looks potentially that the Json parsing to get your input string to the array `addresses` might be failing (so that when you get to this stage in the code, it's not the two parsed Json strings you're expecting). You could try setting a break point on this line in the debugger, and checking what `addresses` is equal to?
2. Sometimes with LINQ it can be tricky to see what's going on until after the lambda call (`x =>` ...) has been returned. To get around this you can set a temporary variable:

   ```
   var temp = addresses.ToList();
   ```

   and then you can use this value to check what happens with the first element in the list `temp`, if you apply the following steps in your code. Stepping through with the debugger may help to see where the error is coming in?

Again apologies that this is just a list of possible ideas, but hope you're able to solve your problem!

Comment: I had tried those options, but my code was throwing an exception before the temp variable was set, I was under a deadline, so wasn't able to explore more, thanks for the ideas though!